# Does every Cube World city have all crafting buildings?

Tags: cube-world

I've been hopping about my little voxel-y world for a little while now, cooing over Alpacas and killing weird creatures of varying varieties.

(For reference, all these links are to the Cube World wiki)

Some of the creatures which needed killing may have in fact been [bushes](http://wiki.cubeworldforum.org/index.php?title=Bushes).

I'd like to turn the [logs](http://wiki.cubeworldforum.org/index.php?title=Wood_Log) that these evil bushy creatures drop into [wooden cubes](http://wiki.cubeworldforum.org/index.php?title=Wood_Cube#Wood_Cube). To do this, the linked wiki says I need a saw, which can be found in the crafting district of a city.

Now, I'm no great shakes at navigation/orienteering, but after a while spent running around in circles, I'm convinced my generated city (Kurtar) does not have a sawmill/saw. What do I do now?

**Does every city in Cube World have every crafting station? If not, how do I go about crafting certain things?**

Answer (score 2):

Every city will have each district as you would expect (crafting, adventurers, pet, and trade) and each of those districts will always have the shops related to them inside. They may be difficult to find at times, but if you zoom in your map the icons for them will show up and help you find them.

The crafting district is easiest to figure out without the icons, tho. Simply look at your map for different colored buildings. For example, woodworking area is a brown building, and the blacksmith is a dark grey.

Answer (score 0):

Every city in Cube World has a Saw Mill. The best way to find it is by pressing M and zooming in until you can see icons on the screen. You will be looking for a saw looking icon. Move to the icon and there, there will be a building. Inside will have a sawmill. Hope this helps! Good luck.

Comment: Did this answer really add anything? It doesn't have any information not in JLaBella's answer, and both question and answer are several months old...

Comment: @Amadeus9 It has a bounty, trying to help -.-

Comment: @Bananaman848 it doesn't have a bounty :S

Comment: @shanodin Thought it did! ._.

Answer (score -1):

Every Cube World city should generate every building, but this does not mean it will always happen. For the most part, any given city should have all buildings, but lacking one or the other may occur, if not rarely. Since Cube World is randomly generated based on a seed, sometimes you'll find a city that lacks a building you'd expect it to have, or you'll find one that has two or even three of a given building type.

You're looking for the [Woodworker](http://www.cubeworldwiki.net/index.php/Cities#The_Woodworker) shop, where you should find a saw you can use to chop up the logs.

If you haven't got one of those in your city, you'll have to load another world or look for another city.

Comment: This really doesn't answer my question. You basically just say "the city should have a woodworker, but it might not."